# Passing stdin to pdflatex gives `Please type a command or say \end`

Tags: pdftex

I have a simple tex file:

```tex
\documentclass{article}\begin{document}

Hi world.

\end{document}
```

When I pass it to `pdflatex` over stdin (`cat tmp.tex | pdflatex`), it correctly produces the output pdf `texput.pdf`, but trips on each newline, saying

`*(Please type a command or say '\end')`

as shown here:

```
% cat tmp.tex | pdflatex             

This is pdfTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.22 (TeX Live 2021) (preloaded format=pdflatex)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
**entering extended mode
LaTeX2e <2020-10-01> patch level 4
L3 programming layer <2021-02-18>
(/usr/local/texlive/2021basic/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2020/04/10 v1.4m Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/local/texlive/2021basic/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo))
(/usr/local/texlive/2021basic/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3backend/l3backend-pdftex.d
ef) (./texput.aux)
*(Please type a command or say `\end')
*
*(Please type a command or say `\end')
*[1{/usr/local/texlive/2021basic/texmf-var/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map}]
(./texput.aux)</usr/local/texlive/2021basic/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfo
nts/cm/cmr10.pfb>
Output written on texput.pdf (1 page, 11848 bytes).
Transcript written on texput.log.
```

It seemed like a workaround would be to replace each newline with `\\`, thereby giving `pdflatex` one long line of input. Indeed, `pdflatex --help` says

```
Alternatively, if the first non-option argument begins with a backslash,
interpret all non-option arguments as a line of pdfTeX input.
```

(In this case, the first non-option argument is the first line of stdin: `\documentclass{...`.) However, replacing all the newlines with `\\` doesn't seem like the right approach. When I tried this in my larger .tex file, `pdflatex` ran out of memory.

I suspect that I need to put `pdflatex` in a mode where it reads stdin like a file. But I tried

```
cat tmp.tex | pdflatex -interaction=nonstopmode
```

and

```
cat tmp.tex | pdflatex -interaction=batchmode
```

and neither of them produced the pdf, and their .log files showed the error

```
*** (job aborted, no legal \end found)
```

So my question is: **What is the right way to pass stdin to `pdflatex` without it getting confused when it hits a newline?**

Comment: It's not confused, it simply logs a `*` (you should only get a `*`  for each line and just  instances of `Please type a command` at the start and end and blank lines,  You can always write to a tmp file `cat tmp.tex > zz.tex; pdflatex zz`

Comment: The presence of `(Please type a command or say '\end')` suggests that `pdflatex` thinks it's listening to human input, instead of receiving a file on stdin. Is there a way to tell it that it's receiving a file on stdin, so it won't clutter stdout with those messages?

Comment: No, you are dealing with a 1970's era commandline interface ...